# Creating Java Environment Variable using Atom

Tags: java, cmd, environment-variables

I try to search to create Java environment variable but the only thing I found is how to accessing it. Also I already search if any other user ever ask on how to create Java environment variable using code builder, also I didn't found any result as what I'm looking for. Can anyone explain on how to create Java environment variable using code builder?

Comment: Environment variables are created (and stored) by the operating system (the environment) you use to start Java. Neither Java or Code Builder are used to create environment variables.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch but I see some code they are using ProcessBuilder. What was that for?

Comment: Okay. That's the one exception, if you are starting another process then you can use ProcessBuilder to create environment variables specifically for that sub process programmatically. You almost certainly don't need or want to do it, because there are probably better ways to solve the problem than spawning another process but you do you.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch okay. But why do we exactly need to create/use environment variables?

Comment: Often they're used to store configuration information. You might have a DATABASE_PASSWORD environment variable, that way you can use your same code in your test environment and your production environment and just override the environment variable to point to the different DB.

Comment: Because the program (or script) you are running uses them to do something. I'll give you an easy example: `System.out.println(System.getenv("PATH"));` (I'd have used HOME, but `System.getProperty("user.home")` is better in Java).

Comment: Understood! Thank you for the clarifications!